# How did antonyms "ungodly" and "unearthly" come to have the same meaning and usage today?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Inspired by the debate on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34055/what-does-the-phrase-ungodly-hour-really-mean),

**unearthly** has the original meaning from [1610s, of "heavenly, sublime"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=unearthly) which makes it an antonym of **ungodly**.

Today both have the meaning of outrageous or ridiculous and are used in similar phrases as "ungodly hour" and "[unearthly hour](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unearthly)"

How has this developed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look a little further in your Etymonline reference, you see that *unearthly* acquired its pejorative usage around 1802:

> Sense of "ghostly, weird" first recorded 1802.

Partridge records the first reference of *an unearthly time* from 1865.

I can find no citation to explain these particular transformations, but you should remember that *unearthly* also easily describes things that are *ungodly*. Beings that were not considered to be part of this world were in the domain of the "spirit world" — which is believed to exist by some even today, and which includes the malicious as well as the sublime.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you've read the debate properly. Neither word **means** 'outrageous'; the basic meaning in each case is exactly what you would expect from the etymology: 'evil or dishonest' and 'unlike anything on earth' respectively.    There being less demand nowadays for these precise meanings than there was (except in parts of Nevada), the meanings have been extended.  Music that is an *ungodly racket* is deeply unpleasant; it might also be described as an *unearthly racket* exactly as it might be said to *sound like nothing on earth*. These are certainly used (and in the dictionary) as synonyms for 'unpleasant' (originally jocularly).  But if you say that, because of this use, the two words mean the same you will rapidly reach the conclusion that all adjectives mean either *good* or *bad*.

Comment: There are dictionary references for meanings "outrageous and ridiculous"

Comment: Sorry @Tim, I don't think this addresses the question as posed, but also the OPs assertion that both phrases mean 'ridiculous/outrageous' is [pretty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unearthly) [well](http://thesaurus.com/browse/unearthly?page=3&qsrc=121) [documented](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ungodly).